# Gerkin and Cucumber in Angular 5: Undefined

Tags: protractor, cucumber, angular5, gherkin

When I try to create a test using Cucumber and Gherkin I get a strange error. I show you the error first, then the files login.step.ts and login.po.ts:

// Error:

```
 Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         When('Enter the card number in the box', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });
```

// login.step.ts

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
const { Given, When, Then, Before } = require('cucumber');

import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
import { LoginPage } from './login.po';

  let login: LoginPage;

  Before(() => {
    login = new LoginPage();
  });

  Given(/^Entering in Login$/, { timeout: 10 * 5000 }, async () => {
    await browser.get('http://localhost:49152/login');
  });

  When(/^Enter the card number in the box$/, () => {
    // login.setCardNumber('1234').then((txt) => {
    //   return 'ready!?';
    // })
    login.setCardNumber('1234');
  });
```

// login.po.ts

```
import { browser, by, element, until } from 'protractor';

export class LoginPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/login');
  }

  setCardNumber(cardNumber) {
    const input = element(by.css('#box'));
    return input.sendKeys(cardNumber);
  }

}
```

The first test passes successfully, but in the second test, the process ends in error.

[EDIT]
Adding the protractor.conf.js file:

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        // './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts',
        './e2e/features/*.feature'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['disable-infobars']
        },
        metadata: {
            browser: {
                name: 'chrome',
                version: '58'
            },
            device: 'Xubuntu Linux',
            platform: {
                name: 'Linux',
                version: '16.04'
            }
        }
    },
    directConnect: true,
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    plugins: [{
        package: 'protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin',
        options: {
            automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
            removeExistingJsonReportFile: true
        }
    }],
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['./e2e/steps/**/*.ts', './e2e/support/*.ts'],
        tags: [],
        dryRun: false,
        compiler: [],
        format: 'json:reports/results.json',
        strict: true
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    framework: 'custom',
    onPrepare() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the double quote `"` behind `box` in  `/^Enter the card number in the box"$/`

Comment: Sorry, but was my error in the moment creating this issue, in that place I'd a regular expression and I was want to do my question more easy to understand..  Sorry again

Comment: Please show  the `cucumberOpts` in your protracot conf.js, and the scenario in feature file

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have modified my thread by adding the contents of the protractor.conf.js file

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem. I only had to include the following configuration line to my Before() step in my test:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

According to what I read in different places, it seems that Chrome is looking to perform some task with sockets, and with this line we are disabling this task.